# Reduce on list of promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a list of jobs that should be sequentially executed.
As the jobs take seconds to be finished the should run in the background.
I thought that a job could be described as

```
interface Job {
    name: string
    execute(): Promise<boolean>
}
```

I would like to have a function which takes this list of jobs and execute them sequentially
until the list is completed or one job fails or is rejected, so basically:

```
function executeUntilFailed(jobs: Job[]): Promise<boolean> 
{
    // execute first job
    // if this job
    //   - returns with true: continue with the next job
    //   - returns with false: resolve the promise with false
    //   - got rejected: reject the promise with the reason prefixed with the jobs name
    //
    // if there are no more jobs to do, resolve the promise with true
    //
    // basically it's a reduce operation with starting value of true and 
    // early stops if one job yields false or got rejected
}
```

I'm rather new to Javascript/Typescript and have a hard time implementing this.

Thanks,
Dieter

Comment: `async function executeUntilFailed(jobs: Job[]) { for(const job of jobs) {if (!await job.execute()) {return  false};} }`. Not much to it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Aluan Hadded and ehab.

I collected their solutions and have now the following code,
which does exactly what I need:

```
    interface Job {
        name: string
        execute(): Promise<boolean>
    }


    async function executeUntilFailed(jobs: Job[]) {
        for (const job of jobs) {
            try {
                if(!await job.execute()) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            catch (err) {
                throw new Error(`${job.name}: ${err.message}`)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

and here is some example for it

```
    class JobImpl implements Job {
        constructor(public name: string, private value: boolean, private throwMsg: string|null = null) {}
        execute(): Promise<boolean> {
            console.log(`executing job '${this.name}'`)
            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                setTimeout(()=> {
                    if(this.throwMsg!=null) { reject(this.throwMsg) }
                    else { console.log(`finished job '${this.name}' with result: ${this.value}`); resolve(this.value) }
                }, 1000)
            })
        }
    }

    const successJobs = [
        new JobImpl("a", true),
        new JobImpl("b", true),
        new JobImpl("c", true),
    ]

    const failedJobs = [
        new JobImpl("d", true),
        new JobImpl("e", false),
        new JobImpl("f", true),
    ]

    const throwingJobs = [
        new JobImpl("g", true),
        new JobImpl("g", true, "undefined problem"),
        new JobImpl("i", true),
    ]


    executeUntilFailed(successJobs)
        .then((res) => console.log("resolved", res))
        .catch((err) => console.log("rejected", err))

    executeUntilFailed(failedJobs)
        .then((res) => console.log("resolved", res))
        .catch((err) => console.log("rejected", err))

    executeUntilFailed(throwingJobs)
        .then((res) => console.log("resolved", res))
        .catch((err) => console.log("rejected", err))

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative, you could create a generator and then use the `for await ... of` syntax:

```
function * chainJobs(jobs) {
    for (const job of jobs) {
        yield job.execute().catch(err => new Error(`${job.name}: ${err.message}`));
    }
}

async function executeUntilFailed(jobs) {
    for await (const result of chainJobs(jobs)) {
        if (!result) return false;
        if (result instanceof Error) throw result;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this either with a reduce function or a for of loop, i will show an implementation in a for of

```
async function executeUntilFailed(jobs) {
  for (const job of jobs) {
    try {
     // notice that if a job resolved with false then it is considered a successful job
     // This is normal and a promise resolved with false should not be considered an error
      await job.execute()

      // if u want based on your description to resolve the whole promise with false if one of promises resolved with false you could do
     // const jobResult = await job.execute()
        // if (jobResult === false) {
           //  return Prmise.resolve(false)
       //  }
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(`${job.name}_${err.toString()}`))
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true)
}
```

lets see the function in action

```
const successJobs = [{
    name: "a",
    execute: () => Promise.resolve(1)
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    execute: () => Promise.resolve(2),
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    execute: () => Promise.resolve(3)
  },
]

const failedJobs = [{
    name: "a",
    execute: () => Promise.resolve(1)
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    execute: () => Promise.reject(new Error("undefined problem")),
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    execute: () => Promise.resolve(3)
  },
]

async function executeUntilFailed(jobs) {
  for (const job of jobs) {
    try {
      await job.execute()
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(`${job.name}_${err.toString()}`))
    }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true)
}


console.log(
  executeUntilFailed(successJobs)
  .then((res) => console.log("resolved", res))
  .catch((err) => console.log("rejected", err))
)


console.log(
  executeUntilFailed(failedJobs)
  .then((res) => console.log("resolved", res))
  .catch((err) => console.log("rejected", err))
)
```

Comment: You don't need and shouldn't use `Promise.resolve/reject` because in an `async` function you can just use `return` and `throw`. Otherwise, this is exactly right.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes i'm aware of that but i still prefer to state them explictily

Comment: So, when you have an `async` function that doesn't return a value, do you end it with `return Promise.resolve(undefined)`? because you should if so. Regardless, that is an extremely unusual practice. Why do you do that?

Comment: @AluanHaddad if  u never throwed  and never returned a value then an async function will be resolved with undefined, but thats not good practice , adding Promise.resolve(undefined) will not make it any better. A promise should be resolved with a value and rejected with an Error ( not even a value that is considered falsy) - obviously  just my option

Comment: @AluanHaddad i prefer to explicitly resolve or reject, because sometimes when writing complex async functions, and you return a falsy value, or even an error, it will easy to mistake this as a rejection, however when the resolve or reject is explict this confustion is much harder to happen

Comment: I strongly disagree. The whole point of `async` enable the use of standard control flow constructs. If you don't use `throw` you shouldn't use `try` and `catch`. Another reason not to do this is because you are coupling your code to the global `Promise` object even on platforms that natively support `async` (including all modern browsers), this likely prevents optimizations and definitely introduces complexity. Finally, you are going to confuse anyone who reads your code

Comment: And, there are many times it's perfectly fine for an `async` function to just `return`.  You don't need an explicit return value.  Promises are often useful just as an indicator for when something is done, even without a specific resolved value.  So, just doing a `return` or letting the `async` function just finish both signify that the body of the `async` function is done and the promise that was previously returned from it can now be resolved.  After you get more experience programming with `async` functions, this will feel natural to you without doing `return Promise.resolve(undefined)`.